# How to direct the replies to a specific email address?

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, office-automation

I am using python to auto-send an email in **Outlook** to a given person. What I would like to do is **direct their replies to a specific email address**.

I know that `ReplyRecipients` is a property of Mailitem, but this seems to be read-only.

Below is my current code.

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'ToEmail@gmail.com'
mail.Subject = 'Test email'
mail.Body = 'This is a test email'
mail.Send()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MailItem.ReplyRecipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.replyrecipients) property is read-only. But the property returns a [Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients) collection that represents all the reply recipient objects for the Outlook item where you can add or remove recipients.

```
Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 
Set myRecipient = myItem.ReplyRecipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev") 
 
myRecipient.Type = olCC
```

Comment: thanks, can this solution be applied similarly in Python?

Comment: nevermind, I was able to convert successfully thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Based on the answer of Eugene Astafiev, I just added

```
mail.ReplyRecipients.Add("reciever@mail.adress.org")
```

and this filled the "Reply-to" field in the e-mail header correctly.